# use complex number to traverse neighbors in 2d array

Tags: python, algorithm

I find a new way to traverse the quartet neighbors by using complex number in this solution.

https://leetcode.com/problems/word-search-ii/discuss/59804/27-lines-uses-complex-numbers

(you can just read my example.)

I think it is elegant and concise, but I can not fully understand about it.

Here I have extracted the key code, and simplify the exmaple.

`board` is a 2d array, and we want to start from every node, and traverse the 4 direction neigbor recursively by dfs:

this is a common way:

```
    def dfs(i, j, word):
        # create 4 direction by hand
        for I, J in (i + 1, j), (i - 1, j), (i, j + 1), (i, j - 1):
            # need to check boundary
            if 0 <= I < len(board) and 0 <= J < len(board[0]):
                dfs(I, J, word + c)

    for i, j in board:
        dfs(i, j, '')
```

here is using complex number as index:

```
    board = {i + 1j * j: c
             for i, row in enumerate(board)
             for j, c in enumerate(row)}

    def dfs(z, word):
        c = board.get(z)

        # here is visit 4 direction neighbors, which I don't understand
        if c:
            for k in range(4):
                search(node[c], z + 1j ** k, word + c)

    for z in board:
        dfs(z, '')
```

I think there is two advantages by using complex number:

1. don't need to create 4 direction by hand
2. don't need to check boundary

But I can't understand here `for k in range(4): dfs(z + 1j ** k, word + c)`

can somebody explain this algorithm? really appreciate it.

Comment: I would assume it has something to with the four cardinal directions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what I think is correct this solution uses the following property of the imaginary number `j`:
[image: j^1, j^2, j^3, j^4 = j, -1, -j, 1]

which if added to a complex number as a representation of a grid are the nodes: right, up, left, down